# The feeling when a familiar object is missing or in a different place

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

If someone has misplaced a familiar object like a wedding ring or wristwatch, they might say they "feel naked without it", or that it's "like a missing tooth".

It's not exactly "pining" for something, and "[Saudade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saudade)" or "[Sehnsucht](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sehnsucht)" is too extreme.

The person might not even realize which item is missing, or it may not be missing at all, only moved to a different place; but because of habit the person expects it to be in its old place.

Is there a noun or noun phrase for this feeling that is more specific to misplaced objects than "disorientation", "nagging uneasiness or "lingering anxiety"?

Comment: sometimes I've heard people express that faintly unsettled sensation as "feeling a bit lost"

Comment: [Jamais vu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamais_vu), perhaps?  The opposite of *deja vu*.

Comment: I don't think there is, I've always had to use a full sentence to describe that feeling. I could write up an answer, and make it official, but that's not really answering your question, because I don't think your question has an answer.

Comment: I'm hesitant on whether or not this would make a good answer; you might call this *withdrawal* in the sense of definition 1.c.2. in [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/withdrawal).  This would be strictly metaphorical, however- couch-in-the-north-west-corner withdrawal doesn't have the same ring as heroin withdrawal.

Comment: Agree with Michael Broughton. She'd **feel lost** without her wedding ring. He **felt lost** when his wife was away for the weekend.

Comment: While it's true that "feeling a bit lost" is analogous, it doesn't function well as a noun or noun phrase.

Comment: This can be termed a bungled act. (see Freud) You put your keys in the fridge instead of their usual hook.

Comment: I've never heard the phrase "like a missing tooth". Is it supposed to refer to sensing a gap with your tongue when a tooth has been pulled and no implant is in place yet?

Answer (score 2):

What about "bereft", as in, "bereft of his watch, his wrist felt naked"?

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. It is not encouraged to post an answer without any research/reference/link that can support it. Please edit your answer after taking the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visiting our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Comment: I'm looking for a noun or noun phrase.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're looking for a noun phrase, you could say "the *lack* of ." For instance, you could say something like, "He felt discombobulated for lack of (or want of) his pocket watch."